# Xamarin Refit - Could not load assembly error

Tags: xamarin, refit

I am new to Xamarin platform and just give it a try this week.
And when I import Refit and use it somewhere, it come out this error:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets: Error: Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'Refit, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
File name: 'Refit.dll'
```

How to resolve this? it seem like android related error but I no idea how to solve it, I new to C# as well.

Thanks for help

Comment: Make sure you install Refit into both your PCL and platform specific project.

Comment: yeah, after add it to all platform, it work now, thanks :)